# Why does DB2 return -1 when deleting all rows in a table?

Tags: db2

The question says it all. Using the Python API as an example:

```
import ibm_db
#setup stuff
conn = ibm_connect(DATABASE, user, password)
stmt = ibm_db.exec_immediate(conn, 'DELETE FROM sometable')
print(ibm_db.num_rows(stmt)) # prints -1
```

Why doesn't it print the *actual* count of rows deleted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an answer, really, just showing that the function does work and that SQLCODEs cause python exceptions. The fact that `num_rows()` does not work for you may indicate that the functionality may not be supported by the database you're connected to. You may want to describe your environment in detail: the DB2 server version and platform, whether it's a local or remote database, the DB2 client version (if different from the server) etc.

```
  >>> import ibm_db
  >>> conn = ibm_db.connect('TEST',user,password)
  >>> stmt = ibm_db.exec_immediate(conn, 'create table t (f int)')
  >>> print ibm_db.num_rows(stmt)  # DDL statement - num_rows not applicable
  -1
  >>> stmt = ibm_db.exec_immediate(conn,'delete from t')
  >>> print ibm_db.num_rows(stmt)  # 0 rows deleted
  0
  >>> stmt = ibm_db.exec_immediate(conn,'delete from x')  # nonexistent table - exception
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  Exception: [IBM][CLI Driver][DB2/LINUXX8664] SQL0204N  "USER.X" is an undefined name.  SQLSTATE=42704 SQLCODE=-204
  >>> stmt = ibm_db.exec_immediate(conn,'insert into t(f) values (1),(2),(3)')
  >>> print ibm_db.num_rows(stmt)  # 3 rows inserted
  3
  >>> stmt = ibm_db.exec_immediate(conn,'delete from t')
  >>> print ibm_db.num_rows(stmt)  # 3 rows deleted
  3
  >>> ibm_db.close(conn)
  True
  >>>
```

Answer (score 0):

A negative SQL Code in DB2 means an error:
[SQL codes](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2z10.doc.codes/src/tpc/db2z_sqlcodes.htm)

Comment: Yes but it's not an SQL code; it is the return code from the `num_rows()` call. You may want to try [enabling the DB2 CLI trace](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r1/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.trb.doc/doc/t0054958.html) to see what is happening behind the scene.